# How should six-four chords be resolved?

Tags: theory, chords, harmony, chord-theory, voice-leading

In the point deduction section of the AP Music Theory exam guidelines, it says:

> The 6th or 4th of a 6 4 chord is unresolved or resolved incorrectly.

What exactly does this entail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a little unclear exactly what you mean, but I'm guessing this is in reference to the cadential or pedal (also known as "neighbor") six-four chord.

Typically, these chords resolve to a root-position triad, and *the bass doesn't move, but the upper voices do*.

And typically, **these upper voices will move down by a step each**: the 6th above the bass will resolve down to the 5th above the bass, and the 4th above the bass will resolve down to a 3rd above the bass. This correct resolution is shown at **A** below.

[image]

Incorrect resolutions would have both of these pitches either moving up or moving down by skip. One of these is shown at **B** above.

Comment: what's the difference between this example and a IVc - I ?

Comment: @AricFowler I'm not sure what you mean by "IVc." Can you elaborate?

Comment: In example A, there's an Esus2sus4 followed by an E minor. However, the first chord could easily be interpreted as A minor in second inversion

Comment: How do you know that it's a six-four, when it could easily just be a second inversion chord?

Comment: @AricFowler Make sure you're reading in treble clef! Also, a six-four chord *is* a triad in second inversion. The "six-four" is the figured bass for a second-inversion triad.

Answer (score 0):

In traditional harmony (and it's a good idea to stick to traditional harmony in an AB exam) a 6/4 chord conventionally resolves to a 5/3 chord on the same bass note.

Or you could extend the journey...   But, like I said, an AB exam isn't the place to be clever!

[image]